# can we deploy jmeter in kubernetes with selenium integration?

Tags: selenium, kubernetes, jmeter

I have deployed jmeter in kubernetes by using

https://github.com/kubernauts/jmeter-kubernetes

But I am facing difficulties when I want to integrate selenium webdriver with jmeter in kubernetes.  I see there is no official documentation to deploy in distribute environment like in kubernetes. I just want to know is it possible to deploy jmeter with webdriver in kubernetes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not? It's just a matter of installing [WebDriver Sampler Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler)

Looking into the repository you provided I can see that all the "magic" of JMeter Plugins installation is being performed in [Dockerfile-base](https://github.com/kubernauts/jmeter-kubernetes/blob/master/Dockerfile-base) so you need to just add a line like:

```
RUN cd /jmeter/apache-jmeter-$JMETER_VERSION/ && wget -q -O /tmp/jpgc-webdriver-3.3.zip https://jmeter-plugins.org/files/packages/jpgc-webdriver-3.3.zip && unzip -n /tmp/jpgc-webdriver-3.3.zip && rm /tmp/jpgc-webdriver-3.3.zip
```

into the [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/)

Comment: is it chromedriver will be installed automatically? if not, How can I install chromedriver within docker file?

Comment: @ImSanjay Please  post it as another question on stack.  Dmitri T has posted an answer for question you have asked in post.